# Как сменить разрешение на астре

Tags: vmware, astra-linux

Установил астру на vmware player, разрешение этой ОС стоит 800х600. Как изменить разрешение на 1920x1080? ctrl+alt+enter как на ПРО версии не работает

Comment: да как и везде — смотрите вывод программы `xrandr`. если не показывает других конфигруаций x-сервера кроме текущей, то вопросы к используемой вами системе виртуализации (vmware или как оно там правильно называется).

Answer (score 0):

В vmware esxi для этого необходимо в самой виртуальной машине сделать настройку смены разрешения рабочего стола. vmware сама перересует сразу разрешение. Предположу что данная опереция сработает и для vmware player